# Bitcoins sent to address i cannot access, funds are unused Pls Help me get them back

Tags: transactions, address

So yesterday i was sending some bitcoin to deposit on my whaleclub.co account like i had done once previous before with no issues, although this time it is saying that my bitcoins were sent to a different address other than mine. As i look at my coinbase transactions and follow the transaction my sent bitcoins remain in that address. How do i get them back ? Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Hi Alex -- let us know what bitcoin addresses you have the private keys for (but don't publish the private keys themselves, obviously!) Have you accidentally sent Bitcoin to an address for which you don't have a key? If it's an account controlled by whaleclub.co, perhaps they can reverse the transaction by sending the bitcoin back.

If you have sent the coins to an account for which nobody has the key, then I'm afraid they are pretty much lost for ever: the blockchain does not allow transactions to be reversed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to see in the blockchain transactions that your amount remained sent to the correct address - then I would contact the support centre with  whaleclub.co.

If you can verify in the blockchain that your btw was sent the correct address, then it sounds like an issue on the receiving end?

Not sure if this helps.